# Compilation problem using PJSIP

Tags: iphone, sdk, voip, sip, pjsip

iam getting the following errors when compiling  PJSIP

Makefile:1: build.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:2: build/host-.mak: No such file or directory

I am new to this iphone development.Please help.

Comment: Have you followed the *Getting started* tutorial of PJSIP here: http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow the instructions given in:
http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone
If it still doesn't work, try using gmake instead of make. 
From your error logs it looks like you are not in the pjproject directory while executing make.